# Can I get the ID/name of database that a stored procedure is called from?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure (logging procedures) that all other stored procedures execute to log their use. 
Now I would like to add what database the stored procedures that is being log is in. 
I would like to get the ID or name of the database the executes the logging procedures in the logging procedures.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not pass it in as a parameter?

Comment: Does it logs the error or success of other stored procedures in a database ? can you please post the sample data from log table

Comment: It logs datatime, procedure name and runtime of the procedure in a separate system log database. If I wanted to send it in as parameter is because I would have to change all my procedures. I’m trying to get away with changing only one.

Comment: Why not change the code?

Comment: I have lots of code

Comment: Are all your procedure names unique?  Or are some of your procedure names the same in two or more databases?

Comment: They have unike names now but they don't need to, and i know this guy named Murphy

Comment: Did you checked my answer, you can still do it without changing all the SPs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no other way without modifying the procs to do this, the best approach is using DB_NAME on the client procs

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DB_NAME()` to retrieve current database name. You should pass it as parameter to your logging procedure.

```
USE Database1

SELECT 
    CurrentDatabase = DB_NAME()
-- CurrentDatabase = Database1

USE Database999

SELECT 
    CurrentDatabase = DB_NAME()
-- CurrentDatabase = Database999
```

---

```
DECLARE @CurrentDatabase VARCHAR(100) = DB_NAME()

EXEC LogDatabase.dbo.LoggingProcedure
    @DatabaseName = @CurrentDatabase
    -- OtherParameters
```

Comment: This is how the log is setup now, but I'm hoping to avoid change all the procedures to add a parameter.